# How to filter on set of ID values without using subquery

Tags: database, oracle

I was wondering if someone can help me, I need to [show this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5LVo.png) in oracle.

For that I use this select:

```
SELECT m.idMedicamento, m.nombre, m.precio
FROM medicamento m
WHERE m.idMedicamento IN (
        SELECT idMedicamento 
        FROM (
            SELECT idMedicamento
            FROM medicamento
            ORDER BY precio ASC)
        WHERE ROWNUM <=3
    )
    OR m.idMedicamento IN (
        SELECT idMedicamento 
        FROM (
            SELECT idMedicamento
            FROM medicamento
            ORDER BY precio DESC)
        WHERE ROWNUM <=3    
    )
ORDER BY m.precio DESC;
```

but the problem is that I can't use subselects I need to use functions or procedures, and I thought in this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MAXI RETURN FLOAT IS
total INT := 0;
CURSOR ANIO IS
    SELECT idMedicamento
    FROM medicamento
    ORDER BY precio DESC;
a anio%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
OPEN ANIO;
LOOP
    FETCH ANIO INTO a;
    EXIT WHEN ANIO%NOTFOUND;

END LOOP;
CLOSE ANIO;
RETURN ROUND(a ,2);
END;
```

This is a function just for return the maximum, but I can't return the cursor. I dont know if you can understand me, thanks for your time.

Comment: *" I can't use subselects "* Why?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot return a cursor and use that in a SQL statement `WHERE` clause the way you seem to want to do.

You could write a function to return the id values you are looking for as a `TABLE OF NUMBER` but you would still need to use a subquery to access its results in your main query.  I.e.,

```
WHERE idMedicament IN ( SELECT * FROM TABLE(my_custom_function()) )
```

So, I think a function to returns the values of `idMedicamento` that you want to filter on is not going to work well with your "no subqueries" limitation.

---

### Alternate approach #1

Incidentally, on Oracle 12c, you can write your query with no subqueries and no functions like this:

```
SELECT m.idMedicamento, m.nombre, m.precio,
case when rownum() over ( order by idMedicamento asc ) <= 3
       or rownum() over ( order by idMedicamento desc ) <= 3 THEN 'Y' ELSE null END include_flag
FROM medicamento m
ORDER BY include_flag nulls last, m.precio DESC
FETCH FIRST 6 ROWS ONLY;
```

### Alternate approach #2

I assume you cannot use subqueries because you are using a tool or a framework that is building your SQL for you.  If that is the case, perhaps you cannot use windowing functions (i.e., `rownum() over (...)`) either.  You can get around this by making a view and then writing your query against the view.

Like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW medicamento_v AS
SELECT m.idMedicamento, m.nombre, m.precio,
rownum() over ( order by idMedicamento asc) asc_order,
rownum() over ( order by idMedicamento desc) desc_order
FROM medicamento m;

SELECT m.idMedicamento, m.nombre, m.precio
FROM   medicameno_v m
WHERE ( asc_order <= 3 OR desc_order <= 3 )
ORDER BY m.precio DESC;
```